# Show that $\min_{a \in \mathbb{R}} E \left[ \max \left( (1-a) V, a Z \right) \right]$ is minimized by $a$ such that $0<a<1$

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value

Consider two independent random variables  $V$ and $Z$. Assume that $Z$ is standard normal. We only assume that $E[|V|]<\infty$ and $E[V]=0$.

Now consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{align}
\min_{a \in \mathbb{R}} E \left[ \max \left( (1-a) V, a Z \right) \right],
\end{align}

Can we show that the minimizer must be such that $0<a<1$? Or is there a counter-example?

Here is what it tried. Assume that $a<0$ and $|a|<1$ then
\begin{align}
E \left[ \max \left( (1-a) V, a Z \right) \right]&=E \left[ \max \left( (1+|a|) V, -|a| Z \right) \right]\\
&= E \left[ \max \left( (1+|a|) V, |a| Z \right) \right] \text{ using } Z \stackrel{d}{=}-Z\\
& \ge  E \left[ \max \left( (1-|a|) V, |a| Z \right) \right]
\end{align}
where in the last step we used that
\begin{align}
(1+|a|) V \ge  (1-|a|) V
\end{align}
provided that $V>0$. So this clearly is **not** correct, but I just wanted to show the idea I had.

**Edit:**  I implicitly assumed that $V$ is not equal to a constant (i.e., zero). Otherwise, the solution is independent of the sign of $a$ as pointed out in one of the answers.

**Edit 2:** Just to give an example I worked out. That I think is cool. Let $V$ and $Z$ be standard Gaussian.  Then, using that $\max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$ we have that
\begin{align}
E \left[ \max \left( (1-a) V, a Z \right) \right]= \frac{1}{2}E \left[  \left| (1-a) V- a Z \right| \right]= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi}} \sqrt{ (1-a)^2+a^2}
\end{align}

Comment: can you just do the proofs for contradiction first for a<0 then a>1 separately? why do them at the same time like that

Comment: @sjw Maybe, but I couldn't figure it out. I tried to put my thoughts and what I have tried.

Comment: Isn't $E \left[ \max \left( (1-a) V, a Z \right) \right] = 0$ regardless of $a$? That is, $$\begin{align}\max \left( (1-a) V, a Z \right) &= \begin{cases} (1-a)V, &(1-a)V \geq aZ \\ aZ, &(1-a)V < aZ\end{cases}\end{align}$$ and so $$\begin{align}E \left[ \max \left( (1-a) V, a Z \right) \right] &= \begin{cases} E[(1-a)V], &(1-a)V \geq aZ \\ E[aZ], &(1-a)V < aZ\end{cases} \\ &= \begin{cases} (1-a)E[V], &(1-a)V \geq aZ \\ aE[Z], &(1-a)V < aZ\end{cases} \\ &= 0\end{align}$$ since $E[V] = E[Z] = 0$.

Comment: @mhdadk you have a mistake in your second step.  These should be conditional expectations.  I have added Edit2 which shows that if both $V$ and $Z$ are Gaussian then there is a clear dependence on $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to limit the solution to the open interval $a \in (0,1),$ because when for instance $(X,Y)$ is standard Normal, the global minimum is attained on the entire closed interval $[0,1]$ and, as you can readily compute, when $X$ is a nontrivial mixture of two Normals the global minimum is attained only at $a=0$ or $a=1.$  I will show that all global minima are attained for $0 \le a \le 1.$

**The key idea** is that when $Z$ is any random variable with finite expectation and distribution function $F_Z,$

$$E[Z] = \int_{-\infty}^0 -F_Z(z)\,\mathrm dz + \int_0^\infty 1 - F_Z(z)\,\mathrm dz.$$

This solution makes (far) weaker assumptions about the variables $X$ and $Y$ than assumed in the question. I will highlight the assumptions needed as we go along.

---

For any bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ and real numbers $a,b,t,$ define

$$g_{X,Y}(a,b) = E[\max(aX, bY)].$$

When $a \gt 0,$

$$E[\max(aX, bY)] = E\left[a\max\left(X, \frac{b}{a}Y\right)\right] = a E\left[\max\left(X, \frac{b}{a}Y\right)\right] = a\,g_{X,Y}\left(1,\frac{b}{a}\right).$$

**When $X$ and $Y$ are independent** with marginal distribution functions $F_X$ and $F_Y,$ and $a$ and $b$ are positive,

$$\begin{aligned}
\Pr(\max(aX, bY) \le t) &= \Pr(aX\le t,\ bY\le t)  \\&= \Pr\left(X\le \frac{t}{a}\right)\Pr\left(Y\le\frac{t}{b}\right) \\&= F_X\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)F_Y\left(\frac{t}{b}\right).
\end{aligned}$$

Thus

$$\begin{aligned}
g_{X,Y}(a,b) &= a\,g_{X,Y}\left(1,\frac{b}{a}\right) \\&= a\left[\int_{-\infty}^0 -F_X\left(t\right)F_Y\left(\frac{at}{b}\right)\mathrm dt + \int_0^\infty \left(1 - F_X\left(t\right)F_Y\left(\frac{at}{b}\right)\right)\mathrm dt\right].
\end{aligned}$$

**Provided $g_{X,Y}(a_0,b_0)$ is defined and finite for some $a_0\gt 0$ and $b_0\gt 0,$** $g_{X,Y}(a,b)$ is defined and finite for every $a\gt 0$ and $b \gt 0$ because $\max\left(aX, bY\right) \le \max(a/a_0,b/b_0) \max(a_0X,b_0Y)$ implies $$g_{X,Y}(a,b)\le \max\left(\frac{a}{a_0}, \frac{b}{b_0}\right)\,g_{X,Y}(a_0,b_0) \lt \infty.$$

Comparable relations hold in the other three quadrants (where $a\lt 0$ and $b\gt 0,$ $a\lt 0$ and $b \lt 0$, or $a\gt 0$ and $b\lt 0$).

**Assume now that $F_Y$ is everywhere differentiable** with derivative $f_y.$  $g$ is differentiable with derivatives $Dg = (D_1 g, D_2 g)$ given by differentiating under the integral signs.  After doing so, substitute $t = by/a$ to obtain

$$\begin{aligned}
a\, D_1 g_{X,Y}(a,b) &= g_{X,Y}(a,b) - b\int F_X\left(\frac{by}{a}\right) y f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy;\\
b\, D_2 g_{X,Y}(a,b) &= b\int F_X\left(\frac{by}{a}\right) y f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy.
\end{aligned}$$

Consequently, for $a\gt 0$ and $b \gt 0,$

> $$a D_1 g_{X,Y}(a,b) + b D_2 g_{X,Y}(a,b) = g_{X,Y}(a,b).\tag{*}$$

Because

$$g_{X,Y}(a,b) = g_{-X,Y}(-a,b) = g_{X,-Y}(a,-b) = g_{-X,-Y}(-a,-b),$$

relationships analogous to $(*)$ hold in all four quadrants.

It follows that the function $a\to g_{X,Y}(1-a, a)$  is *increasing*  for $a \gt 1$ and *decreasing*  for $a \lt 0.$  Here is an illustration where $Y$ has a standard Normal distribution and $X$ is a mixture of Uniform$(-3,-1)$ and Uniform$(0, 1)$ distributions (with zero mean):

[image]

This contour plot for the same $(X,Y)$ is characteristic of the situation:

[image]

The bold line plots the locus of $(1-a,a).$  When this line exits the first quadrant into the second (upper left) or fourth (lower right) quadrants, its component in the direction of the $(a,b)$ vector field described by $(*)$ is *positive:* thus, $g$ increases along the rays parameterized by $(a\mid a \gt 1)$ and $(-a\mid a \gt 0).$

The following conclusions are immediate from the foregoing assumptions (namely, that $(X,Y)$ is independent, $Y$ has an absolutely continuous distribution, and there exist points in each of the four $(a,b)$ quadrants where $g$ is finite):

1. $g$ is continuous everywhere and differentiable on the set $\{(a,b)\mid a\ne 0, b \ne 0.\}$
2. $g$ increases in all directions away from the origin.
3. Therefore the restriction of $g$ to any line attains at least one global minimum,
4. and that minimum occurs in whatever quadrant in which that line is bounded.

Because the line parameterized by $(1-a,a)$ is bounded in the first quadrant and its intersection with that quadrant corresponds to the interval $a\in [0,1],$ we are done.

Comment: Thanks. This is really nice proof.  I am going to go through it very carefully. I hope you don't mind if I ask you questions.  Is this something that you have seen before?

Comment: No, this is a truly original question.  I am curious about the circumstances that motivated it.